# Executing cd and pwd in java program

Tags: java, unix, exec

I have a java program which executes cd unix command as follows:

```
Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -c cd test_dir");
```

Now when I try to do a pwd I'm getting the dir where my java program resides and not the dir which was changed to (should be /root/test_dir)

```
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pwd");
```

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

A child process can't change the working directory of the parent. You could use [`ProcessBuilder.directory(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory-java.io.File-) to set a working directory for the child process. Something like,

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("pwd");
pb.directory(new File("test_dir"));
pb.inheritIO();
pb.start();
```